# wpf usercontrol resizing with thumb not firing DragDelta

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a Usercontrol that I would like to make resizable using the thumb control. I have added my control to a Canvas and when I click on the thumb control the only events that are fired are Dragend and DragStart (in that order) and DragDelta is not even firing. I have found someone with a similar problem [Thumb inside an ItemsControl not firing DragDelta event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556384/thumb-inside-an-itemscontrol-not-firing-dragdelta-event/51822909#51822909) but there is no way I can ask them if they found a solution.

This is the code :

```
    <UserControl x:Class="test.ucChair"
                         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                         mc:Ignorable="d" 
                         d:DesignHeight="53" d:DesignWidth="93" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="Beige" 
                         >  
    <Grid Name="grd" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectAngle"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ZIndex="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="53"  /> <!--  Width="93" Height="53"-->
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Text="OPEN" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="93" KeyDown="txtName_KeyDown" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" Cursor="Hand" TextAlignment="Center"/> 
        <Thumb Name="thmbResize" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="15" Width="15"
                   DragDelta="OnResizeThumbDragDelta" 
                   DragStarted="OnResizeThumbDragStarted" 
                   DragCompleted="OnResizeThumbDragCompleted" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        </Thumb>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ucChairLeft.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ucChair : UserControl
    {
        public ChairType AngleType;
        //?? public int SectionID;

        public ucChair()//ChairType CType)//?, int _SectionID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void OnResizeThumbDragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DragEnd");
            Mouse.Capture(null);
        }

        private void OnResizeThumbDragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DragDelta");
        }

        private void OnResizeThumbDragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.Capture(this);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DragStart");
        }

    }
}

<Window xmlns:test="clr-namespace:test"  x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Background="LightBlue">
        <test:ucChair Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Yellow"/>

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure, if you posted your complete code or not, it is firing for me on .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: I have added all of the code for the project and even changed to using .Net 4.5.2 and DragDelta still doesn't fire (I'm using VS 2013). Any ideas why this could be?